# netbsd installation on ibook g4, boot: load-size is too small

Tags: macos, unix, netbsd

I downloaded NetBSD-6.1.5-macppc.iso and burned it with the "disk utitlity" of a mac (have a german version, don't know extactly how the tool is called in english versions) to a cd-rom.

on the system, where i am planning to install the os I typed the following in the openfirmware console:

```
boot cd:0 NETBSD.MACPPC
```

I hear the sound of the cd-drive, then i get this:

```
boot cd:0 NETBSD.MACPPC DISC-LABEL: LOAD (noninterposed) notsupported-loadsize=0 adler32=1

LOAD-SIZE is too small!
```

Answer (score 0):

Some powerpc macs are quite fussy about the bootloader, and I seem to recall there were some changes which cause issues with older macs.

As a test it might be worth trying a netbsd-5 or netbsd-4 ISO to see if it boots for you